# Why doesn't parsing option work in chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

I have this basic chart that works fine when **parsing: true** ...

```js
myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        options: {
            animation: false,
            parsing: true,
            normalized: true,

            scales: {
                y: {
                    suggestedMin: 0,
                    suggestedMax: 100,
                },
                x: {
                    type: 'time'
                },
            },

        },
        data: {
            labels: [Date.parse("2022-01-01 00:00:00"), Date.parse("2022-01-02 00:00:00"), Date.parse("2022-01-03 00:00:00"), Date.parse("2022-01-04 00:00:00"), Date.parse("2022-01-05 00:00:00"), Date.parse("2022-01-06 00:00:00"), Date.parse("2022-01-07 00:00:00")],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [2, 4, 6, 12, 26, 24, 57]
                }]
        },
    });
```

... however, if i set **parsing: true** then it no longer works - the line doesn't show up.

I'm using chart.js version 3.1 - any ideas what could be stopping parsing: false from working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it fails when you set parsing to false since you say it works and doesn't work when it's true.

When parsing is set to false you need to provide your data in the correct form chart.js uses internally. You are not doing that at the moment.

To change it to the internal data structure you need to remove the labels array and in your data array you put objects which have an x and y key which are the x axis and y axis value for that point

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lee... I thought that by using Date.parse() I was providing data in the correct form, but I guess I was mistaken. I'll try your suggestion of x and y keys and see if that helps

Comment: That worked, thank you Lee...  for anyone who needs it, i'm passing data in like so:

[{x: 1649074060000,
y: 23.39}, ... ]